# How do I set the text color of a Cocoa tooltip?

Tags: cocoa, colors, tooltip

I am using `BGHUDAppKit` for an outline view within a HUD-style (black) `NSPanel`.  As such the text in my outline view cells is light gray or white.  Unfortunately this means that when I hover to bring up a tooltip for a cell's value, it shows up as light gray text on yellow, which is illegible.

How can I set the text color for the tooltip, or is there a way that I can modify the control itself (without changing its appearance) to work better with the tooltip mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `- (void)drawWithExpansionFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)view` in a NSCell subclass to draw whatever you want in the (tool tip) expansion frame.

Comment: My solution ended up being to swap out the text color (store the original in a local variable) and rely on the existing drawWithExpansionFrame:inView: code, then reinstate the original color afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Adem Preble's suggestion, I ended up with a `NSTextField` subclass, which overrides `drawWithExpansionFrame`, and uses a simple color toggle trick:

```
@implementation MyCustomTextField

- (void)drawWithExpansionFrame:(NSRect)contentFrame inView:(NSView *)view     {
    NSColor *originalColor = self.textColor;
    self.textColor = NSColor.labelColor; // Or any other NSColor
    [super drawWithExpansionFrame:contentFrame inView:view];
    self.textColor = originalColor;
}

@end
```

This works because the expansion tooltip with the adjusted color covers the text field behind it, with the freshly reset color.